# How to hide Button if Job is successfully executed in angular 7

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have a mat-button and instead of making them disabled I want them to become hidden once Job is successfully executed and to show if it fails.
I have tried using `[hidden]` tag but it doesn't seem to work.
Code for HTML

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let index = index">
                <button
                    *ngIf="index === 0"
                    mat-icon-button
                    (click)="stop_exec_job(element)"
                    matTooltip="Stop Executing the Job"
                    [disabled]="
                        element.status == 'SUCCESS' ||
                        element.status == 'FINISH' ||
                        element.status == 'CANCELLED'
                    "
                >
                    <!-- Edit icon for row -->
                    <i class="material-icons" style="color:red"> stop </i>
                </button>
                <!-- Delete icon for row -->
                <button
                    *ngIf="index === 0"
                    mat-icon-button
                    (click)="re_run_job(element)"
                    matTooltip="Re-Run the Job"
                    [disabled]="
                        element.status == 'RUNNING' ||
                        element.status == 'Pending'
                    "
                >
                    <i class="material-icons" style="color:green">
                        cached
                    </i>
                </button>
            </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could've combined the checks in `*ngIf`

```
// First button
<button
    *ngIf="index===0 && element.status!='SUCCESS' && element.status!='FINISH' && element.status != 'CANCELLED'"
    mat-icon-button
    (click)="stop_exec_job(element)"
    matTooltip="Stop Executing the Job">

// Second button
<button
    *ngIf="index===0 && element.status!='RUNNING' && element.status=='PENDING'"
    mat-icon-button
    (click)="re_run_job(element)"
    matTooltip="Re-Run the Job">
```